# How levels(factorObject)[factorObject] generate complete vector?

Tags: r

```
vectorN = c("Hello","How","are","you","you","are","Hello")
factorVectorN = factor(vectorN) 
#Value of levels(factorVectorN) is c("are", "Hello", "How", "you")
all(levels(factorVectorN)[factorVectorN] == vectorN) # returns TRUE
```

Can you please explain, how in above example **levels(factorVectorN)[factorVectorN]** create same vector as vectorN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just basic subsetting. From `help("[")`:

> Indexing by factors is allowed and is equivalent to indexing by the
>   numeric codes (see factor) and not by the character values which are
>   printed

You already show the factor levels. Internally, a factor is just an integer vector, where each number (starting from 1) corresponds to a factor level:

```
str(factorVectorN)
#Factor w/ 4 levels "are","Hello",..: 2 3 1 4 4 1 2
as.integer(factorVectorN)
#[1] 2 3 1 4 4 1 2
```

So, if you subset the levels with these numbers, you get a character vector with the same values as the original factor:

```
str(levels(factorVectorN)[factorVectorN])
#chr [1:7] "Hello" "How" "are" "you" "you" "are" "Hello"
```

If you compare the original factor with the character vector using `==` your factor is coerced to character for this, too.

Answer (score 1):

`levels(factorVectorN)` is an atomic vector of type "character" of length 3

```
class(levels(factorVectorN))
## [1] "character"
length(levels(factorVectorN))
## [1] 3
```

That means that it has 3 entries and you can index them using `[]`.

When you run `levels(factorVectorN)[factorVectorN]` you basically telling R to pull the entries out of `levels(factorVectorN)` that match the index vector called `factorVectorN`

Now, `factorVectorN` contains the following indexes `1 2 1 2 3 2`. So R will pull first entry out if `factorVectorN`, then the second entry, then the first entry again, then the second and so on. Which will return `1 2 1 2 3 2` bacause these are the values of `levels(factorVectorN)` that correspond to the specified index vector